# How to Get(listen) to POST and GET Methods send to my server PHP

Tags: php, post, logging, get, save

hi guys i want to Get all POST and GET Methods which Everyone send to my server web applications and save as log with php. 
how can i do this ? (in xampp)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/510709/possible-to-log-post-get-params-in-apache-2-2

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Answer (score 0):

In a custom log format %r (first line of request) will contain the GET parameters. For just the GET params use %q (query string (prepended with a ? if a query string exists, otherwise an empty string)).

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

For the post data you have to use mod_dumpio.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html